# Mechanism of indexes in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm learning javascript and trying to make my own findIndex function like this

```
function findIndex(array, number) {
  if (number in array) {
    return array.indexOf(number);
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

It finds the index of a number if the number is in the array, when i try it with

```
console.log(findIndex([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)); // returns 2
console.log(findIndex([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 6)); // returns -1
console.log(findIndex([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5)); // returns -1
```

The last one printed out a -1 but when i try to do

```
console.log(findIndex([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4)); //returns 3
```

It prints out the correct index, so for some reason the last index isn't counted by "in" or some other thing i'm missing. Why does this happen?

Comment: `number in array` tests if `array[number]` is present, not if `array[n] === number` for some `n`. Your function should really just be `return array.indexOf(number)` I think. It already returns `-1` if it's not present.

Comment: @CollinD But if it isnt `array[n] === number` shouldn't `console.log(findIndex([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3));` returns something other than 2? (which is the correct index). By the way thank you for your answer it works now.

Comment: Test with this: console.log(findIndex([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 20)); It will return -1. So you will understand that @CollinD is right.

Comment: `3 in [1,2,3,4,5]` is true because you have more than 4 elements. So it passes the check, and then returns `[1,2,3,4,5].indexOf(3)` which is correctly 2.

Comment: @CollinD wait so what im doing is checking if an array is a length of `number` so thats why it still returns true? thanks for this <3

Comment: Wait actually im checking if array[number] is present yeah you right, ily